# How to check performance of a function in kernel

Tags: c, linux, performance, linux-kernel, perf

I am trying to understand and use existing utilities or programmable snippets which allow to measure CPU utilization/performance in terms of Power Consumption, CPU cycles of a function in kernel space.

I have two function snippets which do the same work:

**convert ip address to string.**

```
char* inet_ntoa(struct in_addr in, char* buf, size_t* rlen)
{

        int i;
        char* bp;

        bp = buf;
        for (i = 0;i < 4; i++ ) {
                unsigned int o, n;
                o = ((unsigned char*)&in)[i];
                n = o;
                if ( n >= 200 ) {
                        *bp++ = '2';
                        n -= 200;
                }else if ( n >= 100 ) {
                        *bp++ = '1';
                        n -= 100;
                }
                if ( o >= 10 ) {
                        int i;
                        for ( i = 0; n >= 10; i++ ) {
                                n -= 10;
                        }
                        *bp++ = i + '0';
                }
                *bp++ = n + '0';
                *bp++ = '.';
        }
        *--bp = 0;
        if ( rlen ) {
                *rlen = bp - buf;
        }

        return buf;
}
```

AND

```
char *inet_ntoa (struct in_addr in)
    {
      unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *) &in;
      __snprintf (buffer, sizeof (buffer), "%d.%d.%d.%d",
              bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);

      return buffer;
    }
```

The later function is from glibc. The former one is my own.

The two function would be called in kernel space.
How can I measure there performance to compare.

My machine is Ubuntu 14.04 x86 i686. Linux kernel 3.13

**I Installed perf from source linux/tools.**

**I have my module running. How can I hook perf to measure my functions performance.**

Kindly Suggest.

Comment: Use `perf` tool for that. Like in the below answer is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into [oprofile](http://linux.die.net/man/1/oprofile). The example output (from http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/linux/profile.html)

```
# oprofpp -l -i /foo/vmlinux | tail
c012ca30 488      1.86174     kmem_cache_free
c010e280 496      1.89226     mask_and_ack_8259A
c010a61a 506      1.93041     restore_all
c0119220 603      2.30047     do_softirq
c0110b30 663      2.52938     delay_tsc
c012c7c0 703      2.68198     kmem_cache_alloc
c02146c0 786      2.99863     __copy_to_user_ll
c0169b70 809      3.08637     ext3_readdir
c01476f0 854      3.25805     link_path_walk
c016fcd0 1446     5.51656     ext3_find_entry
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested by [this paper](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-32-ia-64-benchmark-code-execution-paper.pdf) by an Intel engineer.
It explains how to accurately time your code with the CPU timer.

Don't forget to time with a wide range of inputs. You might also want to take into account the potential difference in robustness (how your code behave with wrong inputs).

Comment: summary: first disable preemption and IRQs, then use assembly (`RDTSC` instruction) to read the CPU cycle counter before and after the code

Comment: This is an interesting approach but too synthetic. Not always it possible to turn off preemption and IRQs.

Comment: @SebastianMountaniol Turning off IRQs is better, but you don't have to. In this case you need to test several times and reject high timings that stick out (those that got interrupted).

Comment: It possible but here we fall into the trap of a proper threshold.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing the same thing recently and I am using these tools:

Perf 
[https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page](http://perf%20wiki)

ARM DS5
[http://ds.arm.com/](http://perf%20wiki)

PowerMonitor
[https://www.msoon.com/LabEquipment/PowerMonitor/](http://perf%20wiki)

You can get an evaluation version for ARM DS5 and try it out.
It will profile the code application wise and you can see "online" data.

PowerMonitor is licensed.

Perf is a really handy tool and you can profile for different events.Kernel should be configured for perf events.

It will need some profiling turned on, which can be enabled at the time of Kernel Compilation.

For Perf related information , you can find the guidance here:
[https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial](http://perf%20wiki)

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion, I have installed perf, but how to link perf to measure my functions performance.

Comment: To get started, try `perf record -a`, wait a bit, `Ctrl-C`, then run `perf report`. Make sure your function is actually called often enough, or it won't show up.

Comment: @maxy Does my function need to be exported, although I am not using it in any other module. Will perf require information from exported symbols only ?

Comment: you can find how to enable support for perf, if not already enabled in the attached link

Answer (score -1):

The other answers give good suggestions for precision measuring. If you're looking at rough difference, it may be easier to use something from [timekeeping.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/timekeeping.h), such as `do_gettimeofday`:

```
uint64_t time_one_function(void (*func)(void))
{   
    const int NUM_ITERATIONS = 5000;
    struct timeval before, after;

    do_gettimeofday(&before);
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        func();
    }
    do_gettimeofday(&after);

    // Time it took to do all iterations in microseconds
    uint64_t diff_microseconds = (after.tv_sec - before.tv_sec) * 1000000ULL + (after.tv_usec - before.tv_usec);

    // REturn roughly the time in nanoseconds for a single call
    return (diff_microseconds*1000) / NUM_ITERATIONS;
}
```

That will give a rough nanoseconds time for a single function, then just call it on both.